# Trigger is working fine for inserting records but not working on update of records

Tags: trigger, lookup, dml, before-trigger

I have written a trigger to update one lookup field of invoice with salesquota object id.This triggers work fine when i am inserting records.But when i try to update records with few changes it is not working.I have written two formula field for comparision. On changing records formula evaluates to be false but still that lookup field is not updated.if formula evaluates to false then that lookup field should be null or blank.Something i am missing in the code.Not able to figure out.

Trigger:

```
trigger InvoiceTrigger on Invoice_CU__c (before insert, before update) {
    if(Trigger.isbefore && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        System.debug('value of trigger.new :::::  '+Trigger.new);
        List<Sales_Quota__c> salesQuotas = [SELECT SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c, SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c from Sales_Quota__c];
        for(Sales_Quota__c sq:salesQuotas){
            for(Invoice_CU__c inv:Trigger.new){
                System.debug('value of Invoice_Text_Formula__c :::::: '+inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c);
                System.debug('value of SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c :::::: '+sq.SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c);
                if((inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c)  && (inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c)){
                    inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = sq.id;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i am adding else condition to make lookup field as null then in all case of update of records even without changing any records lookup field become null.

Comment: You say `On changing records formula evaluates to be false but still that lookup field is not updated.if formula evaluates to false then that lookup field should be null or blank` so it seems like it is doing what it is supposed to do. If the formula is not supposed to be false you need to look at why the formula is false when it should not be

Comment: Yes it is not updating that lookup field.i need to avoid condition in which if formula evaluates to false then lookup field must be null or blank.

Comment: then add use and "if ... then...else..." branch that if the formula field is null do xxx and if not do xxx...

Comment: if((inv.Invoice_Text_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Text_Formula__c)  && (inv.Invoice_Date_Formula__c == sq.SalesQuota_Date_Formula__c)){
                    inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c = sq.id;
                }else{
inv.InvoiceToSalesquota__c =null;
}
when i add else condition then on every update it is making lookup field as null even when formula field comparision condition is true.

Comment: @Eric-correct me if i am going wrong way.

Comment: No. Since you are looping through the Quotas, and then the invoices when the invoices match one, they do not match the others they will not be set properly. They way you have it, the logic sets the values according to the *LAST* quota in the list. not sure of your data structure but you should put the quotas in a collection and GET the right one, otherwise maybe loop through the trigger records then move the quotas loop inside that and break the quota loop when you find a match for the outer invoice loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42069/discussion-between-robert-barnett-and-eric).

Comment: only 1 scenario is not working when formula field comparison evaluates to false and there is no salesquota records in that lookup field value should be blank but here it is retaining old lookup field value.

Comment: I have fixed this issue by separating code of insert and update of records. Incase of insert of records i kept the same code but in case of update first i am making lookup field blank by looping all Trigger.new and update lookup id to null. Then i have used same logic as insert of records.